# Fully Javascript POS

Tags: javascript, point-of-sale

I'm looking for a POS system for a coffee shop chain that allows for restaurant/retail processing of transactions.

I know there are a lot of options available, but I'm looking for a purely Javascript implementation, backend and frontend. Ideally open source too.

I'm aware of open source options such as https://github.com/fat-tire/floreantpos and https://github.com/frappe/erpnext or even https://github.com/odoo/odoo , but at most these only use javascript for the frontend.

Why is that? Is there truly no fully javascript implementation? Do I need to make one?

I'm building a tech stack for developers only capable of coding in JavaScript.